# How Can I Show PDF Automatically According to It's ID in C #

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a question : I need to show pdf documents without askink what to open to the user. It needs to be matched with a unique id. Let's say I have a product_ID=55435, and I need to open the 55435.pdf by automatically in a windows form.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you follow the steps below:

(1) You can add ActiveX controls provided by Adobe to the toolbox.

Method: Right click on the blank of the toolbox=>choose items=>COM Components=>check AdobePDF Reader=>OK

As the picture shows:[image]

(2) You can drag the Adobe PDF Reader control to the form, create a button button1, and add button events.

The button event code is as follows:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename =; // Example: filename = @"F:\SoftWare\PdfFile\55435.pdf";
        axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename);
    }
```

Running result:[image]

Comment: Hey Arya, thank you so much for your answer! Is there any way that I can open the pdf not on the explorer but in the windows form itself?

Comment: @Uğurcan Çetindağ I have modified it. If this is not your requirement, you can continue to contact me.

Comment: hello again, actually this will work perfect in my project. Thank you !!!